# What was this strange orange and grey plane I saw today?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Sitting out in the backyard today I heard a plane that seemed louder than usual, I turned and saw it immediately, it appeared to be flying quite low compared to the many I’ve watched fly over us in the past. It was also an odd colouring I’d never seen. Orange and dark grey. I didn’t see any text, but it was large like a commercial plane. I live in Northern Alberta, in Grande Prairie, where we really only have the same two companies with the same aircrafts that service the area. I also couldn’t see it on Flight Radar 24 when I immediately went to check what it was.

Any one have any ideas? I couldn’t even find an airline with that colour scheme. And it was gone too fast for me to get a photo despite having a very clear view.

Comment: "Louder than usual" and the colors aren't much to go on.  Prop or jet?  Single, or multi-engine?  Swept wing or straight?  Does it look similar to anything you've seen before?  Please help us by describing in a bit more detail.  (although maybe someone from that province will get it based on color... it could be a military trainer of some sort)

Comment: My first wild guess would be aerial firefighting... do you have ongoing wildfires in your region?

Answer (score 5):

My only guess is a Newfoundland's Canadair CL-415:
[image]

Probably helping your province's firefighters.

Comment: This was pretty much what I was imagining as I typed my comment last night…. Good guess, let’s hope the OP circles back or this will get closed.

Comment: Just to triangulate, Alberta has four CL-215s, [this pic](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Canadair_CL-215s_Alberta_Government.jpg) shows three in yellow-and-orange. Quebec's 215s are blue and orange/yellow. cc @MichaelHall

Comment: and while Alberta Wildfire mostly talks about the helos they are using right now, [this picture on an Aug 11 tweet](https://twitter.com/AlbertaWildfire/status/1557936739259297794) shows the tail of a plane, so they're obviously using fixed wing on recent fires as well.

Answer (score -1):

I know that Jet star (an Australian domestic and international flight company) has colours of grey and orange, and many of their planes are grey and orange, it could've been them.

Comment: Jet Star doesn't fly to Canada.

Comment: Jet Star is – as you said – an Australian operator. Their flights do show up on FR24 and it is highly unlikely that they operated in Canada.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).